# Black screen appearing after splash screen in android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am developing an app in which i had used splash screen. But after splash disappears, then
Next screen becomes black before switching to my main activity and I don't want black screen. Can anyone please suggest me how to do this? 
Here's my code.

**Launcher Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
public static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SplashScreenActivity.class);
synchronized (this) {
try {
wait(50);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
String str = e.toString();
Log.d(TAG, str);
}//catch
}//synchronized block
startActivity(in);
}//onCreate
}//class
```

**SplashScreenAcitvity**

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
private Thread splashThread;
public static final String TAG = "SplashScreenActivity";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
final SplashScreenActivity splashScreen = this;

splashThread = new Thread(){
public void run(){
try {
synchronized (this) {
wait(3000);
}
} catch (Exception e) {
String str = e.toString();
Log.d(TAG, str);
}
finish();
Intent in = new Intent();
in.setClass(splashScreen, ProjectActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
stop();
}//run
};
splashThread.start();
}//onCreate

}//class
```

**Project Activity**
This is the class from where main operation will start.

```
public class ProjectActivity extends TabActivity {
static int x=0;
static int color;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.tabxml);

if(x==1)
{
Dor.c=1;
color = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("color");
//Intent in=new Intent();
//in.putExtra("color",color);
}
Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab
// Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Dor.class);
// Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("dor").setIndicator("Dor",
res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);

// Do the same for the other tabs
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Album.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_album)
.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Forhandler.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("forhandler").setIndicator("Forhandler",
res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_forhandler))
.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Diplomat.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("diplomat").setIndicator("Diplomat",
res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_diplomat))
.setContent(intent);
tabHost.addTab(spec);
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
}
```

I tried with async task but it didn't worked. Here's my modified code:

**ProjectStart**

```
public class ProjectStart extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Void>{
public static final String TAG = "ProjectStart";
/*public ProjectStart() {
    super("ProjectStart");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}*/

Context ctx;
public ProjectStart(Context context){
    this.ctx = context;
}//constructor

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Context... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent in = new Intent();
    in.setClass(ctx, ProjectActivity.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground called");
    return null;
}//doInBackground

/*@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent in = new Intent();
    in.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ProjectActivity.class);
    startActivity(in);
    Log.d("Project Start", "onHandleIntentCalled");
}*/
```

}//class

In SplashScreen.java I did following modifications

```
splashThread = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            try {                   
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(3000);
                }//synchronized
            }//try  
            catch(InterruptedException e) {} 
            finally {
                finish();
                new ProjectStart(sPlashScreen).execute();
                /*Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProjectStart.class);
                startService(in);*/
                stop();
            }//finally
            Log.d(TAG, "run method called");
        }//run
    };
```

And, here is stack trace:

```
  04-19 11:29:02.181: E/AndroidRuntime(341): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
04-19 11:29:02.181: E/AndroidRuntime(341): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-19 11:29:02.181: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at abc.com.camera.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:32)
04-19 11:29:02.181: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
04-19 11:29:02.181: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
04-19 11:29:02.181: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
04-19 11:29:02.181: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
04-19 11:29:02.181: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
04-19 11:29:02.181: E/AndroidRuntime(341):  ... 1 more


    04-19 11:29:02.181: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

I am not getting what is the problem.

Comment: hi can you tell me what you do in your splash screen and main activity

Comment: try to reduce as much code as possible in onCreate() of MainActivity.

Comment: @PankajKumar I had posted code, please check once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Best solution for you is [asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Given is an example from Developer's site. Asynctask has main four Methods.

```
onPreExecute()

doInBackground(Params...)

onProgressUpdate(Progress...)

onPostExecute(Result)
```

And this is other [Example](http://android10.org/index.php/articlesother/239-android-application-and-asynctask-basics).

Comment: Sorry, by mistake I modified your post. As per ypur suggestion, I tried with async task but it didn't worked.

Comment: Using async task I got this exception: E/AndroidRuntime(341): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Comment: @nitish : Can you just have a look at this blog. http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/08/01/android-async-task/

Answer (score 2):

> But after splash disappears, the screen becomes black before switching
>   to my main activity

It seems that you might be doing some Background process on the UI of MainActivity that is taking time to do the Background Process. If so the use

- AsyncTask
- Service
- IntentService

for Background Process. If not the show the Main Activity what code does it have.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the tutorial for more help below links:

http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-make-a-basic-splash-screen/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App

Thanks..!

Comment: Downvoting as the answer makes no attempt at explaining what the cause of the problem might be. The OP is not asking how to make a splash screen, it’s a specific issue they are facing. Simply adding links to some tutorials is about the same as suggesting that they just Google.

Comment: @Ash cool no issues it's my bad :(. I should have given a solution, anyway I answered when I came first to stackoverflow. I made mistakes when i learn first not always. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a flag to your activity intent.. setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION)